# Unrecognized import directory in django

Tags: python, django, deployment

I've a project something like this.

```
main_dir\

    __init__.py

    views.py

    nested_dir\

        __init__.py

        app.py
```

I created some global object(let's call it my_obj) in main_dir/**init**.py, and want to import them in  main_dir/nested_dir/app.py in the followin way.

```
from main_dir import my_obj
```

when I'm trying to call

```
python app.py
```

from nested_dir, it is working locally, but when I deploy my codes in the server, and trying call app.py file, I'm receiving error

```
ImportError: No module named main_dir
```

Does anybody met such problem ?

Comment: Is `main_dir` on your Python path in deployment? It might be trickier to solve the problem if you use `main_dir` and `nested_dir` instead of your actual code.

Comment: yes it is on python path. The thing is that i have  nested_dirs, in one of them it is worked, on of them no

Comment: from where do you call your code on production server and how you do it? try to use relative imports `from .. import my_obj`.